# How to simplify the following expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, syntax, rule

Consider the following expression:

```
expr[s1_, s2_, m_] = 
 Sqrt[s1 (s1 - 4*m^2)] + c Sqrt[s1^3 (s1 - 4*m^2)] + 
  d Sqrt[s1^4 s2^2 (s1 - 4*m^2) (s2 - 4*m^2)]
```

Here, `m > 0 && s1 > 4*m^2 && s2 > 4*m^2`.

Because of this, the expression may be simplified to the following form:

```
expr2[s1_, s2_, m_]=s1*Sqrt[1-4*m^2/s1]+ c*s1^2 Sqrt[1 - (4*m^2)/s1] + 
 d*s1^(5/2) s2^(3/2) Sqrt[1 - (4 m^2)/s1] Sqrt[1 - (4 m^2)/s2]
```

This is what I do for this:

```
Assuming[m > 0 && s1 > 4*m^2 && s2 > 4*m^2, 
 FullSimplify[expr[s1, s2, m]]]
```

But this command does nothing.

Could you please tell me how to simplify it?

Comment: You can't. These are not the same. One way to check is to plugin in some random values in both and see if you get same numerical value. Here is screen shot showing these are not same. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLHUW.png)

Comment: @Nasser : sorry, this is, of course, under the assumptions specified in `Simplify`. I have edited the question.

Comment: Still, they are not the same. Here is screen shot where I set $s1,s2$ as needed. Both still give different numerical results. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgjM8.png)

Comment: @Nasser : it seems that I made a mistake in `expr2`. Corrected it.

Comment: OK, now they give same numerical values for some random input. But note that LeafCount of expr1 is 58 and leafCount for your expr2 is 76. So according to default Mathematica Simplify algorithm expr1 is simpler than expr2.

Comment: @Nasser : I have some complicated expessions similar to `expr1` with random powers inside and outside the square root. In the form of `expr2`, there are very few expressions matching the pattern of `expr2`.

Comment: You might have to write special transformation rules. For example, here in a rule that transforms the first one ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJpMB.png)  If Simplify or FullSimplify does not do what you want, you can use your own rules or use `TransformationFunctions` option. But this needs careful examination of how you want to do the transformation and for each part/expression.  May be someone will have better ideas. Expression transformation is one of the hardest things in CAS and not always easy, that is why people just use `Simplify` command and not worry about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following.
Here is your initial expression:

```
expr1 = Sqrt[s1 (s1 - 4*m^2)] + c Sqrt[s1^3 (s1 - 4*m^2)] + 
  d Sqrt[s1^4 s2^2 (s1 - 4*m^2) (s2 - 4*m^2)]
```

Let us make the following replacements:

```
expr2 = expr1 /. {m -> (Sqrt[s1] Sqrt[x])/2} /. s1 -> y^2 // Factor

(*  Sqrt[-((-1 + x) y^4)] + c Sqrt[-((-1 + x) y^8)] + 
 d Sqrt[s2^2 (-1 + x) y^10 (-s2 + x y^2)]  *)
```

Now one can first simplify the result and only then substitute the replacements back:

```
expr3 = Simplify[expr2, {0 < x < 1, y > 0, z > 0, m > 0, s2 > 0}] /. 
   x -> (4 m^2)/s1 /. y -> Sqrt[s1]
```

To make the result better visible I place below its image:

[image]

This is almost what you want. To transform it to exactly what you want one needs two more operations. First, in the third term, we replace `4 m^2 - s2` by  `Hold[(4 m^2)/s2 - 1]*z^2` where `z^2=s2`:

```
expr4 = ReplacePart[
  expr3, {2, 3, 3, 1, 2} -> Hold[(4 m^2)/s2 - 1]*z^2];
```

[image]

Now, let us simplify the result assuming `z>0` and substitute the initial variable:

```
(expr4 // Simplify[#, z > 0] &) /. z -> Sqrt[s2] // ReleaseHold
```

[image]

One can also expand the result if desired.

Done. Have fun!